# Hadoop - what should be the key and value

Tags: hadoop

I am a Hadoop newbie.

My objective is to upload a large no. of files with different extensions onto a Hadoop cluster and get an output as follows :

Extension     No. of files

.jpeg         1000
.java          600
.txt          3000

and so on.

I'm assuming that the file name must be the key to the mapper method so that I can read the extensions(and in future, do other File operations)

```
          public void map(Text fileName,
                   null/*will this do - value isn't required in this case*/,
                   OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output,
                   Reporter reporter)
                   throws IOException
           {
            Text extension = new Text(FilenameUtils.getExtension(filename));
            output.collect(extension, 1); 
        }

          public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException { 
          int sum = 0; 
          while (values.hasNext()) { 
          sum += values.next().get(); 
          } 
          output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum)); 
          }
          }
```

**Queries :**

1. How to send the file's name as a key to the Mapper? I was thinking of implementing the **RecordReader** interface but was not sure if it is required but also couldn't figure which of the its implementing classes to use !
2. As per the API and my understanding, the **InputFormat** implementation is responsible for providing splits for processing - do I have to do something here to get my job done ?

*Please guide me in case I have made any fundamentally incorrect assumptions pertaining to the concepts of Hadoop MapReduce.*

-------------------1st EDIT-------------------

Attaching the codes,outputs and queries :

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.hadoop.mapred.scratchpad;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Main main = new Main();

        if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Enter path to read files");
        }

        main.groupFilesByExtn(args);
    }

    private void groupFilesByExtn(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        JobConf conf = new JobConf(Main.class);
        conf.setJobName("Grp_Files_By_Extn");

        /* InputFormat and OutputFormat from 'mapred' package ! */
        conf.setInputFormat(CustomFileInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.class);

        /* No restrictions here ! */
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        /* Mapper and Reducer classes from 'mapred' package ! */
        conf.setMapperClass(CustomMapperClass.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(CustomReducer.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(CustomReducer.class);

        CustomFileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }

}
```

Customized FileInputFormat

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.hadoop.mapred.scratchpad;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class CustomFileInputFormat extends
        FileInputFormat<String, NullWritable> {

    @Override
    public RecordReader<String, NullWritable> getRecordReader(InputSplit aFile,
            JobConf arg1, Reporter arg2) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("In CustomFileInputFormat.getRecordReader(...)");
        /* the cast - ouch ! */
        CustomRecordReader custRecRdr = new CustomRecordReader(
                (FileSplit) aFile);

        return custRecRdr;
    }

}
```

Customized RecordReader

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.hadoop.mapred.scratchpad;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplit;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader;

public class CustomRecordReader implements RecordReader<String, NullWritable> {

    private FileSplit aFile;
    private String fileName;

    public CustomRecordReader(FileSplit aFile) {

        this.aFile = aFile;

        System.out.println("In CustomRecordReader constructor aFile is "
                + aFile.getClass().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String createKey() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fileName = aFile.getPath().getName();

        System.out.println("In CustomRecordReader.createKey() "+fileName);

        return fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public NullWritable createValue() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getPos() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next(String arg0, NullWritable arg1) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Mapper

```
package com.hadoop.mapred.scratchpad;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class CustomMapperClass extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<String, NullWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    private static final int COUNT = 1;

    @Override
    public void map(String fileName, NullWritable value,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> outputCollector,
            Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("In CustomMapperClass.map(...) : key " + fileName
                + " value = " + value);

        outputCollector.collect(new Text(FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName)),
                new IntWritable(COUNT));

        System.out.println("Returning from CustomMapperClass.map(...)");
    }

}
```

Reducer :

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.hadoop.mapred.scratchpad;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;


public class CustomReducer extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text fileExtn, Iterator<IntWritable> countCollection,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("In CustomReducer.reduce(...)");
        int count = 0;

        while (countCollection.hasNext()) {
            count += countCollection.next().get();
        }

        output.collect(fileExtn, new IntWritable(count));

        System.out.println("Returning CustomReducer.reduce(...)");
    }

}
```

The output(hdfs) directory :

```
hd@cloudx-538-520:~/hadoop/logs/userlogs$ hadoop fs -ls /scratchpad/output
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   4 hd supergroup          0 2012-10-11 20:52 /scratchpad/output/_SUCCESS
drwxr-xr-x   - hd supergroup          0 2012-10-11 20:51 /scratchpad/output/_logs
-rw-r--r--   4 hd supergroup          0 2012-10-11 20:52 /scratchpad/output/part-00000
hd@cloudx-538-520:~/hadoop/logs/userlogs$
hd@cloudx-538-520:~/hadoop/logs/userlogs$ hadoop fs -ls /scratchpad/output/_logs
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hd supergroup          0 2012-10-11 20:51 /scratchpad/output/_logs/history
hd@cloudx-538-520:~/hadoop/logs/userlogs$
hd@cloudx-538-520:~/hadoop/logs/userlogs$
```

The logs(only one opened) :

```
hd@cloudx-538-520:~/hadoop/logs/userlogs/job_201210091538_0019$ ls -lrt
total 16
-rw-r----- 1 hd hd 393 2012-10-11 20:52 job-acls.xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hd hd  95 2012-10-11 20:52 attempt_201210091538_0019_m_000000_0 -> /tmp/hadoop-hd/mapred/local/userlogs/job_201210091538_0019/attempt_201210091538_0019_m_000000_0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hd hd  95 2012-10-11 20:52 attempt_201210091538_0019_m_000002_0 -> /tmp/hadoop-hd/mapred/local/userlogs/job_201210091538_0019/attempt_201210091538_0019_m_000002_0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 hd hd  95 2012-10-11 20:52 attempt_201210091538_0019_m_000001_0 -> /tmp/hadoop-hd/mapred/local/userlogs/job_201210091538_0019/attempt_201210091538_0019_m_000001_0
hd@cloudx-538-520:~/hadoop/logs/userlogs/job_201210091538_0019$
hd@cloudx-538-520:~/hadoop/logs/userlogs/job_201210091538_0019$ cat attempt_201210091538_0019_m_000000_0/stdout
In CustomFileInputFormat.getRecordReader(...)
In CustomRecordReader constructor aFile is org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit
In CustomRecordReader.createKey() ExtJS_Notes.docx
hd@cloudx-538-520:~/hadoop/logs/userlogs/job_201210091538_0019$
hd@cloudx-538-520:~/hadoop/logs/userlogs/job_201210091538_0019$
```

As seen :

1. The output on HDFS is a 0kb file
2. The logs show sysout only till the thread is in CustomRecordReader

What is that I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaliyug,

As per your need there is no need of passing file name to mapper. It is already available in mapper. Just access it as below. Rest of it is quite simple, just mimic the simple word count program.

```
  FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)reporter.getInputSplit();
  String fileName = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

In case of new API, **reporter** need to change to **context**

For performance optimization, you can just create a record reader that will simple supply the filename as key to mapper (same approach as above). Make the recordreader not to read any file content. Make the value part NullWritable.

Mapper will get filenames as key. Just emit to reducer < file_extension,1 > as < key,value > pair.

Reducer needs to do the same logic as of wordcount.

Comment: Hi Arun,
Thanks a lot for the pointers !
I have edited my original question - the code I wrote pertains to the 'optimization approach' mentioned in your comment. I'm unclear about the usage of Reporter as suggested by you.
Please assess the code I have written.

Comment: Basically Reporter class comes with the old hadoop API, instead of reporter, just use Context class object, that was what I was mentioning.

Comment: Ok. Can u guide me as to what is the mistake that I have done in the code - the sysouts in Mapper, Reducer aren't coming and there is no error/exception in the job !

Comment: Check for the sysout on the web UI. They dont come on the system console. Just click the map task or the redue tesk attempt id and you can see the sysouts or logs.